# Slick responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, responsive, slick.js

Задача состоит в том, чтобы слайдер включался после `320px` и ниже, а `breackpoint` срабатывал как `320` и выше.

Как правильно сделать?

Имею такую конструкцию:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.review_review').slick({
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 320,
        settings: "unslick",
        slidesToShow: 1,
        arrows: false,
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо развернуть порядок `responsive` - `mobileFirst: true`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.review_review').slick({
        mobileFirst: true,
        responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 320,
                settings: "unslick",
                slidesToShow: 1,
                arrows: false,
            }
        ]
    });
});
```